# We can click any record it refreshes with in page

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery, ajax

My Requirement is:

i have created a custom visual force page. in that one custom object have a number of records, when we click on one record it goes to another tab,

But my requirement is it displays on same page.

Please provide code..

i'l provide my code here:

```
<apex:page controller="adminpage" sidebar="false" id="pg">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>     
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("a#icsFrame").click(function () {
    document.getElementById("myIFrame").src = 'https://c.eu2.visual.force.com/apex/Marketingoverview?isdtp=mn'; 
    });
    $("a#icsFrame1").click(function () {
    document.getElementById("myIFrame").src = 'https://c.eu2.visual.force.com/apex/ActivitytypesPage?isdtp=mn';  
    });
    $("a#icsFrame2").click(function () {
    document.getElementById("myIFrame").src = 'https://c.eu2.visual.force.com/apex/PlanOverview?isdtp=mn'; 
    });
    $("a#icsFrame3").click(function () {
    document.getElementById("myIFrame").src = 'https://c.eu2.visual.force.com/apex/Plantype?isdtp=mn';  
    });
    $("a#icsFrame4").click(function () {
    document.getElementById("myIFrame").src = 'https://c.eu2.visual.force.com/apex/ProjectOverview?isdtp=mn'; 
    });
    $("a#icsFrame5").click(function () {
    document.getElementById("myIFrame").src = 'https://c.eu2.visual.force.com/apex/ProjectType?isdtp=mn';  
    });
    $("a#icsFrame6").click(function () {
    document.getElementById("myIFrame").src = 'https://c.eu2.visual.force.com/apex/TaskOverview?isdtp=mn'; 
    });
    $("a#icsFrame7").click(function () {
    document.getElementById("myIFrame").src = 'https://c.eu2.visual.force.com/apex/Worktasktype?isdtp=mn';  
    });



$("#setupLeaf").toggle();
$("#setupLeaf1").toggle();
$("#plan").toggle();
$("#plan2").toggle();
$("#plan3").toggle();
$("#imageplusrpt").click(function(){

   $("#minus1").show();
   //$("#minus").show();
   $("#setupLeaf").toggle();
   $("#setupLeaf1").toggle();
   $("#setupLeaf2").toggle();    
   $("#imageplusrpt").hide(); 
   //$("#imageplusrpt1").hide();   
  });

  $("#minus1").click(function()
  {

     $("#imageplusrpt").show();
     //$("#imageplusrpt1").show();
     $("#minus1").hide();
    // $("#minus").hide();
     $("#setupLeaf").toggle();
     $("#setupLeaf1").toggle();       
  });

$("#imageplusrpt1").click(function(){  

   $("#minus").show();
   $("#plan").toggle();
   $("#plan1").toggle();   
   $("#imageplusrpt1").hide();   
  });

  $("#minus").click(function()
  {        
     $("#imageplusrpt1").show();     
     $("#minus").hide();
     $("#plan").toggle();
     $("#plan1").toggle();       
  });

  $("#imageplusrpt2").click(function(){  

   $("#minus2").show();
   $("#plan2").toggle();   
   $("#imageplusrpt2").hide();   
  });

  $("#minus2").click(function()
  {        
     $("#imageplusrpt2").show();     
     $("#minus2").hide();
     $("#plan2").toggle();       
  });

  $("#imageplusrpt3").click(function(){  

   $("#minus3").show();
   $("#plan3").toggle();   
   $("#imageplusrpt3").hide();   
  });

  $("#minus3").click(function()
  {        
     $("#imageplusrpt3").show();     
     $("#minus3").hide();
     $("#plan3").toggle();       
  });
});
</script>
 <div style="float:right; position:absolute;" class="floatLeft">

 <apex:form >


                   <h><span style="color:#007AA5;"><b>abcd</b></span></h><br/><br/>

                   <div style="Height:20px;">
                        <img src="/img/alohaSkin/setup/setup_plus_lev1.gif" alt="Expand - account - Level " id="imageplusrpt" width="11" height="11" class="setupImage" title="Expand - account - Level "  />    
                        <img src="/img/alohaSkin/setup/setup_minus_lev1.gif"  id="minus1" alt="Collapse - account - Level "  width="11" height="11" class="setupImage" title="Collapse - account - Level " style="display:none;"/>
                        <a href="" id="icsFrame" style="cursor:pointer;text-decoration: none;"><b>account</b></a>
                   <br/>
                        <div id="setupLeaf" style="Height:15px;">                           
                             <a href="" style="cursor:pointer;text-decoration: none;margin-left:40px;" id="icsFrame1">Account Type</a><br/>                       
                        </div>                        
                   </div>

                   <br/>         
</apex:form>
        </div>
<div style="float:left; position:relative;margin-left:12%;color:#FF3300;">
        <table >
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div >

                    <iframe id="myIFrame" name="myIFrame" src="https://c.ap1.visual.force.com/apex/Abcd?isdtp=mn" width="1000" height="450" frameborder="0"></iframe>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </div>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: can you paste your vf page. Search if there is a keyword target="_blank" in your page, _blank attribute loads the content in new tab

Comment: asking you the same, "please provide code" of your custom VF page